# HTTP Patch in azure function

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-functions

I am looking a way to implement proper HTTP Path in Azure function. I have found examples which are checking for null of each of the property and adding it to the entity to PATCH. I found this is not ideal but just a workaround. The only signature I found for HTTP triggered function(v2) is,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "HTTP VERB", Route = "")] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
    {
    }
```

Instead of this I need to pass "**JsonPatchDocument**" and the client would be able to pass PATCH document as below,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "PATCH", Route = "")] **JsonPatchDocument<Customer> patch**,
 ILogger log)
{
}
```

```js
PATCH /api/customer
[
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/firstname",
      "value": "Vijay"
    },
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/email",
      "value": "example@example.com"
    },
]
```

so that I can use "**patch.ApplyTo()**" to path the properties. Is it possible to do in azure function?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467884/how-to-identify-the-http-method-verb-used-to-invoke-an-azure-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I couldn't pass **"JsonPatchDcument"** type to azure function but I could parse the request body to JsonPatchDocument as below,

```
FunctionName("PatchInstitute")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchInstitute(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "patch", Route = ApiConstants.BaseRoute + "/institute/{instituteId}")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log, [Inject]IInstituteValidator instituteValidator, int instituteId, [Inject] IInstituteProvider instituteProvider)
    {
        try
        {
           //get existing record with Id here
            var instituteDto = instituteProvider.GetInstitueProfileById(instituteId);



            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                var requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                //Deserialize bosy to strongly typed JsonPatchDocument
                JsonPatchDocument<InstituteDto> jsonPatchDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPatchDocument<InstituteDto>>(requestBody);

                //Apply patch here
                jsonPatchDocument.ApplyTo(instituteDto);

                //Apply the change
                instituteProvider.UpdateInstitute(instituteDto);

            }

            return new OkResult();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex.ToString());
           // return Generic Exception here
        }
    }
```

And JsonPathDocument to pass from client would looks like below,

```js
[
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/isActive",
      "value": "true"
    }
]
```

Here you can pass whatever the fields to update (patch)